# Rendering of @Ajax.ActionLink is messed up by adding a new route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ActionLink:

```
<td>
    @Ajax.ActionLink(item.HostedBy, "_DetailsMerged", "Marcher",
            new { id = item.HostedById },
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                UpdateTargetId = "marcherId" + @i ,
                HttpMethod="GET",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            })

</td>
```

that displays the appropriate link when I just have default routing. However, introducing a route for a geolocation proxy, (which implments `IRouteHandler` and is a custom route handler) BEFORE the default routing:

```
routes.Add("WebgisUscproxy", new Route("WebgisUscproxy", new OpenLayers_Bronze.Utility.WebgisUscProxyHandler()));

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
 );
```

while working OK for semi-hard-coded links in my client javascript ajax call (that look like: `/WebgisUscproxy?zip=10003`), screws up how the `@Ajax.ActionLink` links are rendered. They ALSO pick up `'/WebgisUscproxy'`. So I get:

```
http://localhost:59723/WebgisUscproxy?action=_DetailsMerged&controller=Marcher&id=1
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost:59723/Marcher/_DetailsMerged/1
```

which is what I want, and get with just the default routing. Putting:

```
routes.Add("WebgisUscproxy", new Route("WebgisUscproxy", new OpenLayers_Bronze.Utility.WebgisUscProxyHandler()));
```

AFTER the default route handler also doesn't work, as the default routing now matches semi-hard-coded links, like `'/WebgisUscproxy?zip=10003'`.

==========================================================================

I've found a work-around, though I hope somebody posts something more direct.

```
routes.MapRoute("webgisusc", "WebgisUscProxy",     
                    new { controller = "Utility", action = "WebgisUsc" }
                    ).RouteHandler = new OpenLayers_Bronze.Utility.WebgisUscProxyHandler();
```

I had created an empty Utility controller, and was going to add a dummy "WebgisUscProxy"
action to it, but it turns out that there's no need for even a dummy UtilityController. This route definition works, all by itself.

Comment: That was awesome! :-). I had to add a /{*path} to my url, but otherwise I think your own solution merits an upvote as answer.